# Datagrid cell style with converterParameter

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

How to use converterParameter in a style setter on a datagrid cell? 
I need to know the element name or property name in my converter.

xaml:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <view:IsEnabledCellConverter x:Key="IsEnabledCellConverter"/>
    <Style x:Key="CellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" 
                Value="{Binding 
                        Path=Item,
                        Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=IsEnabledCellConverter}, 
                        ConverterParameter={?????}}"
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}} />
    </Style>
.../...

<Datagrid>
     <DataGrid.Columns>
         <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Design" 
                             CellStyle="{StaticResource CellStyle}" 
                             Value="{Binding Path=Design}"/>
         <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="FooBar" 
                             CellStyle="{StaticResource CellStyle}" 
                             Value="{Binding Path=Foobar}"/>
     </DataGrid.Columns>
</Datagrid>
```

Converter class:

```
class IsEnabledCellConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string p = (string)parameter;
        MyItem item = (MyItem)value;

        switch (p)
        {
            case "Design":
                return string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Reference);
                break;
            case "FooBar":
                return item.Something != true;
                break;
            default:
                return true;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

EDIT: I added some detail for understanding the needs.
So all my columns IsEnabled props are binding this global Converter for two reasons:

1. it's easier to maintain
2. some column need to be enabled depending of the value of other item values.

Comment: In your question, which element name or property name are you looking for.

Comment: I would like to retrieve the x:name of DatagridTextColumn or the Binding Path property eg "Design"

Comment: Any good reason for doing so. If yes, you might have to use `AttachedProperty`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `DisplayIndex` or `Header`, and set `ConverterParameter` accordingly.

```
<Style x:Key="CellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Column.DisplayIndex, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="0">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" 
                    Value="{Binding 
                            Path=Item,
                            Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=IsEnabledCellConverter}, 
                            ConverterParameter=0,
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}}" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Column.DisplayIndex, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="1">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" 
                    Value="{Binding 
                            Path=Item,
                            Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=IsEnabledCellConverter}, 
                            ConverterParameter=1,
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}}" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Please tell if this solves your problem.

Comment: @ebelair 100% it is working, with proper ConverterParameter. I check before posting.

Comment: @ebelair if suitable, you can come on chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18165/wpf

Comment: No it's okay it's working. Sorry i forgot to add CeelStyle to the first and second column ^^"

Comment: But i don't understand why this is not possible : ConverterParameter=Column.DisplayIndex ? 
It would be so much simpler

Comment: @ebelair Its because of XAML syntax rules. You cant write anything anywhere.

Comment: @ebelair And yes you can always create your own Binding class by extending Binding class and make ConverterParameter accept anything you like.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123836/discussion-between-ebelair-and-anjumskhan).